# shortcode for sitelogo and siteurl in wordpress? (contact form7)

Tags: wordpress

hi there I'm new to wordpress and I can see that the plugin contact form 7 has a shortcode to output fields. But I was wondering how do I output shortcode of the site's logo and home url?

I read that it has something to do with functions.php, but I get more confused when I see the samples. Can anyone explain to me how I could achieve what I need? Thank you

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: What theme are you using? Where do you want to output your logo?

Comment: i'm using betheme which my company has provided i tried the solution provided it works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in your function.php

```
// get site url
wpcf7_add_shortcode('cf7_siteurl', 'cf7_custom_siteurl', true);
function cf7_custom_siteurl(){
    return get_site_url();
}

// get logo url
wpcf7_add_shortcode('cf7_logourl', 'cf7_custom_logourl', true);
function cf7_custom_logourl(){
    return get_header_image();
}
```

Contact for 7 custom shortcode:
`[cf7_siteurl]` :site url shortcode 
`[cf7_logourl]` :logo url shortcode